# Dynamic parameters in JSON serializable class

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am trying to create a JSON object with `json` library from Python 2.7. I am creating a class with needed parameters to serialize like:

```
class DataMessage:
    channelID = 0
    messageID = 0
    timestamp = 0
    voltageRMS = 0
    currentRMS = 0
    voltageDC = []
    currentDC = []
```

But when serializing it to JSON I need the name of the parameters to change regarding channelID. For eg: when channelID=1 the data should be serialized like:

```
{
    "messageID" = id,
    "timestamp" = 32432,
    "voltageRMS1" = 548,
    "currentRMS1" = 5548,
    "voltageDC1_1" = 43,
    "voltageDC1_2" = 44,
    "voltageDC1_3" = 45,
    # ....
    "currentDC1_1" = 32,
    # ....
}
```

I didn't find any functionality in this library that will exclude some of the serialized parameters (`channelID`) or to dynamically create an array of `params(voltageDC[])`.

So, the details for the JSON serialised message:

1. `voltageRMS1` - refers to the fact that `channelID = 1`
2. `voltageDC[]` array will expand for each value in `voltageDC_1 = ...`
3. `channelID` will not be serialized, just taken into consideration for parameters names.

Comment: No, there won't be any functionality that does this exactly, because that is rather specialised. Just generate a dictionary with those keys; the keys are just strings, so they are easy enough to produce according to your rules.

Comment: Try to write something on your own to improve your skills. If you will fail, then let us know, but paste what you did/found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement a custom [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) for your class that unpacks each array:

```
from json import JSONEncoder

class MyEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        result = {
           'messageID': o.messageID,
           ...
        }

        for n, item in enumerate(o.voltageDC):
            result['voltageDC{}_{}'.format(o.channelID, n)] = item

        # and so on...

        return result
```

You can then call `json.dumps()` with your custom encoder class to get the JSON output:

```
dm = DataMessage()
...
json.dumps(dm, cls=MyEncoder)
```